# Glassfish 4.1 answers with bad request, but 3.1.2 not

Tags: java, http, glassfish

I'm using jax-rs on glassfish 3.1.2 and plan to migrate to glassfish 4.1. But after doing some tests I discovered that one of our client apps sends http request with two 'Content-type' strings:

```
PUT /api/v4/topTen HTTP/1.1\r\n
Content-Type: application/json\r\n
Content-Length: 5105\r\n
Host: 10.19.76.2:8080\r\n
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient 1.0\r\n
Accept: application/json\r\n
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n
```

The problem is that glasshfish 4.1 does not accept this request and answers with '**400 Bad request**', but glassfish 3.1.2 processes it perfectly.
Unfortunately I can't change the the client because it was published and many people use it.

**Is there any way to tune 4.1 to accept such request and process it?**

Answer (score 0):

Try with adding content-length in your request header.

Comment: What do you mean by adding content length to the header? As I said I can't modify the header on the client side. On the server side my rest service wasn't called at all. Is it possible to interfere with the header on the server side to fix it before it gets rejected? Thanks